# How To Remove 'Preload Key Request Error' in Google Page Speed Insights

Tags: css, wordpress, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I can't get rid of the Google Page Speed Insights warning about preloading key requests.

It is pointing to CSS Files hosted on my server.

I've added information to my header and have verified that can be viewed in the code.  Note I'm using Wordpress.

My code looks like this:

```
<link rel="preload" href="my css file link" as="style">
```

And still can't get rid of this error. Thanks

Comment: there are loads of reasons this might not be working. The one I see most often is that there is a character difference between the server URL and the preload URL (it is case sensitive as well in some browsers which is surprising). The other thing is `crossorigin` needs to be added on some CDN items. At the moment there isn't enough information to help, could you add a link to the PSI report, or a link to the site, or create a fiddle that recreates the problem so we can help.

Comment: thank you.  the domain is allvintagecards.com   i'm also seeing this error in webmaster tools " 
The resource https://allvintagecards.com/wp-content/plugins/wpfront-scroll-top/css/wpfront-scroll-top.min.css?ver=2.0.2 was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally."

Comment: When I run it I don't get a error from PSI but in the console I can see you are preloading a script but not using it. This appears to be a mistake as you have preload on `...thrive-dashboard/js/dist/frontend.min.js?ver=2.3.5.2` but appear to only use `thrive-visual-editor/editor/js/dist/frontend.min.js?ver=2.6.3.2` - the different version numbers obviously get treated as different scripts, even if they are actually the same.

Comment: hi i think those might be two different files

Comment: Yes but you preload one and use the other, the `ver=2.3.5.2` one does not appear to be used anywhere.

Comment: it's confusing but i think it's being used--i'm using a theme builder and if you use their backend to create posts those files are necessary even if they show as unused